# saving text area data to Google Datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I don't understand what is going on here.  I have a webpage that accepts user submitted data inside of a textarea box.

Say i have somebody type in this text into the text area,

```
<a href=”http://2.bp.blogspot.com">testing</a>
```

if you submit it, it escapes properly and submits to the database and shows up on the webpage as a link (as it should).

However, say i have the same text in a text file or microsoft word file and you copy and paste the exact same thing into the text area and submit it does not save to the database.  I have no idea how there would be a difference between copying and pasting and actually typing the data into the text area.   does anybody have any idea about this?

thank you in advance,

Comment: My guess is that word formats the double quotes into a special character, so it doesn't validate as HTML.

Comment: As I am looking at my own question i realize that quotes in Microsoft word show up as the quote on the left and the normal quote would be that on the right, it was giving me an error because of that crazy looking quote on the left.  what the hell is that?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark_glyphs - this might give some insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, it was a strictly a microsoft word issue, i did not notice the difference in qotes as seen above.